# Dplyr mutate does not condition correctly on separate (date) column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a time-series dataset in which I would like to refer to a value in a previous year, if it exists. I therefore create a helper column with the date I am referring to and expect the code to retrieve the value from that exact year. However, this is not happening, rather it retrieves the same value in all rows, corresponding to the first possible year.

I use the following code

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

dataset <- data.frame(names=c("a","a","a","a","a","a"),
                      values=c(2,3,4,5,6,7),
                      dates=dmy(c("01/01/2010","01/01/2011","01/01/2012","01/01/2013","01/01/2014","01/01/2015")))

dataset_calc <- dataset %>% 
  group_by(names) %>% 
  mutate(yoy=case_when(dates>=dmy("01/01/2011") ~ dates-years(1),
                       TRUE ~ dmy("01/01/2010"))) %>% 
  ungroup()

final <- dataset_calc  %>% 
 mutate(yoyval= values[dates==yoy])
```

But get this result:

```
  names values dates      yoy        yoyval
  <chr>  <dbl> <date>     <date>      <dbl>
1 a          2 2010-01-01 2010-01-01      2
2 a          3 2011-01-01 2010-01-01      2
3 a          4 2012-01-01 2011-01-01      2
4 a          5 2013-01-01 2012-01-01      2
5 a          6 2014-01-01 2013-01-01      2
6 a          7 2015-01-01 2014-01-01      2
```

Where I'd expect to get the following:

```
  names values dates      yoy        yoyval
  <chr>  <dbl> <date>     <date>      <dbl>
1 a          2 2010-01-01 2010-01-01      2
2 a          3 2011-01-01 2010-01-01      2
3 a          4 2012-01-01 2011-01-01      3
4 a          5 2013-01-01 2012-01-01      4
5 a          6 2014-01-01 2013-01-01      5
6 a          7 2015-01-01 2014-01-01      6
```

Am I not using the conditioning in the square brackets correctly, or do I misunderstand how mutate uses the condition?

Comment: You are not using the conditioning in the square brackets correctly.  Can you describe what you want that final `mutate()` to do?

Comment: First off, you don't need the `group_by()` at all in your code. Secondly, the issue isn't with `mutate`, it's just that vectorised subsetting does not do what you want it to do. Instead, you need `match`.

Comment: You're right I don't need the group_by(), I previously tried to test it with groups but found the issue persisted anyway, just forgot to remove that line. What I want is the last output I posted above, i.e. that for row 3 where `dates=2012`, the column `yoyval` should equal `values` for the row where `dates=2011` as per `yoy`. I'll try looking into `match`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a left_join on the new column yoy with the original dates to find the corresponding values for each year:

```
final <- dataset_calc  %>% 
  left_join(dataset_calc %>% select(values, dates), by = c('yoy' = 'dates'))
```

This gives the desired result.

If you want to incorporate the action in the existing pipeline, you can reference the intermediate result with `eval(.)` and perform a sort-of self join:

```
dataset_calc <- dataset %>% 
  group_by(names) %>% 
  mutate(yoy=case_when(dates>=dmy("01/01/2011") ~ dates-years(1),
                       TRUE ~ dmy("01/01/2010"))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  left_join(eval(.)  %>% select(values, dates), by = c('yoy' = 'dates'))
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution indeed works for this example. However, I was hoping to use the solution within a pipeline that performs a similar function across different columns in a larger dataset alongside other manipulations, so this solution would require quite a few additional steps and potentially many intermediate datasets. Is there not a way to do so through mutate?

Comment: You can use the left_join in the pipeline just like a mutate. I added the code showing this to the answer.

Comment: Thank you again, that indeed makes it more concise for me. Two follow-up questions: 1) On large datasets, are merging actions like this more or less intensive than an equivalent mutate action (if it existed)?, and 2) What exactly is the issue with my square bracket conditioning that makes the code only refer to one instance of `dates` across all my rows?

Comment: To be honest, I am not certain what the most efficient way is. When finding a corresponding value from another dataset, my first intuition is to use a join. You might want to remove duplicates before the join, that might save some calculation time.

Your second question is about the square brackets. You can test the following code: 
dataset_calc$values[dataset_calc$dates == dataset_calc$yoy] 
(which is what is supplied in the mutate) and you can see it gives only one value, the 2. This is the only case where dates == yoy, so it will use this single number to populate the whole column.